# How to change current directory to the location of batch file

Tags: batch-file

We have a script located in `D:/Proj/run_some_stuff.cmd`. This script runs a python file:

```
python p.py
```

`p.py` is placed in the same folder: `D:/Proj/p.py`

So it is assumed that user goes into `D:/Proj`folder and runs:

```
run_some_stuff.cmd
```

But some users use search to find `run_some_stuff.cmd` and then click on it. As a result, current directory is not `D:/Proj`. And python fails with error:

> python: can't open file 'p.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My question is: is there a way to get to know inside cmd script where it "lives" and then set current dir to that location.

So I mean that `run_some_stuff.cmd` must "understand" that it lives in `D:/Proj/` and then, before launching python, set current dir to `D:/Proj/`.

Comment: Insert `CD /D "%~dp0"` or `Pushd "%~dp0"` at the beginn of the batch.

Comment: Thanks. Exacty what I was looking for.